# How to access JS object property's value

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to pull the survey value from the following javascript object:

```
[{
    "id": "RJLGscviug-dg3zqAAAa",
    "name": "john",
    "room": "dormitory",
    "survey": {"Q1":"A","Q2":"B","Q3":"C"}"
}]
```

However, the console-log statement in my function below returns 'survey' instead of the survey value which is an object. Here is the code I am using:

```
    const getAllSurveys = (users) => {
      var surveys = [];
      for(var user of Object.keys(users)){
        for (var userData of Object.keys(users[user])) {
          if(userData == "survey"){
            console.log(userData);
            surveys.push(userData);
          }
        }
      }
      return surveys;
    }
```

How can I get the `surveys.push(userData)` to push the value and not the name?

Comment: You're over-complicating I think, the object is already inside an array index. Iterate the array, and then `surveys.push(item.survey)` to push the survey object into the surveys array.

Comment: `return users.map(u => u.survey)`…?

Comment: Why are you using a for loop to look for survery?

Comment: `if (userData == "survey") console.log(userData);` — Yes, that‘ll log “survey”, no doubt about it…

Comment: `surveys.push(users[user][userData])` but why you dont just get the value instead of looping on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `surveys.push(users[user][userData])` instead of `surveys.push(userData);`

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```js
const data = [{
    "id": "RJLGscviug-dg3zqAAAa",
    "name": "john",
    "room": "dormitory",
    "survey": {"Q1":"A","Q2":"B","Q3":"C"}
}];

const getAllSurveys = (users) => {
  return users.reduce((a, c) => {
    const userSurveys = Object.keys(c.survey).map(q => c.survey[q]);
    return a.concat(userSurveys);
  }, []);
};

console.log(getAllSurveys(data));
```